# Angular 6: How to set different title of ngBootstrap accordion panel when it is collapsed or not

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, ng-bootstrap

I want to have different titles for panels in an accordion made with ngBootstrap. NgbPanel has a property named isOpen, but how do I get it's value?

Comment: You should add some details on things your tried, code examples and the such. Looks like there is an event that is fired when the panel is toggled/changed that could be used. https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/accordion/api

Comment: Did I mention that I tried something? No, I did not. I just read the documentation. Code examples can be found here: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/accordion/examples , but my question is addressed to people who don't need code examples because they used the component already.

Comment: I was more giving you a tip on how to write better questions that will get answered more often. People want to see what research efforts you put in. Less of 'just do my homework for me' feeling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this StackBlitz: [Dynamic accordion title](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b5n7n1?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

HTML file:

```
<div class="container">
  <ngb-accordion #acc="ngbAccordion" id="accordion" (panelChange)="changeTitle($event, acc)">
    <ngb-panel title="{{ title }}">
      <ng-template ngbPanelContent>
        Content
      </ng-template>
    </ngb-panel>
  </ngb-accordion>
</div>
```

TS file:

```
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';

  title: string = "TITLE WHEN NOT EXPANDED";

  changeTitle($event: NgbPanelChangeEvent, acc) {
    if (!acc.isExpanded($event.panelId)) {
      this.title = "TITLE WHEN EXPANDED";
    } else {
      this.title = "TITLE WHEN NOT EXPANDED";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks, I was on Version 2.0 and there is no method isExpanded